# Shell script file testing

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have to do these steps:

a. Accept the file name as command line argument

b. Check for sufficient number of command line argument.

c. Check if the given file exist or not.

d. Check if the file is readable.

e. Exit out of the program with success using the statement exit 0

This is what i did so far, but when i run the script i always get "Invalid argument" and "File Does Not Exist" as the output.

```
#! /bin/bash
filename=$1

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo $1
else
    echo "Invalid argument"
fi

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "File Exists"
    exit 1
else
    echo "File Does not Exist"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -r "$1" ]; then
    echo "File is readable"
    exit 1
else
    echo "File is not readable"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I suggest that you change the first line to `#!/bin/bash` - i.e. remove the space after the hash-bang. And add this as the second line of the script: `echo $#`. Best of luck.

Comment: @Evogear Are you running your script without an argument?

Comment: @BobJarvis The output is the same with the addition of "0"

Comment: OK, so no arguments are being passed to the script. How are you invoking this script?

Comment: @sokin I think so, the file itself is there, i dont know why it doesnt see it as a command line argument

Comment: @BobJarvis What do you mean?

Comment: When you run your script. what *exactly* are you typing in?

Comment: bash myfilename.sh in the terminal

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax - I'm afraid that shell scripts and C programs are a little different in this case. You're correct that $0 contains the name of the shell script - but if no arguments follow the name of the shell script on the command line `$#` will be 0, not 1.

Comment: You are exiting prematurely if the file exists, and again if the file is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - so, you type in `bash myfilename.sh`. This means that you're running your script but passing no arguments to `myfilename.sh`. Try the following:

```
echo "This is a test file" > testfile.dat
```

This will create a file named `testfile.dat` which contains some text. (The actual text in the file doesn't matter. If you've got time you can type in the complete works of Shakespeare. But it won't change how your shell script functions). Next, run your script as

```
bash myfilename.sh testfile.dat
```

or just

```
myfilename.sh testfile.dat
```

Here you're telling your script to check for the existence of `testfile.dat`.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked, the output now shows as follows: 1 \n testfile.dat \n File Exists

Comment: An addition if someone reads this and also needs help, removing the exit 1 from the if statements makes the output shows both "File Exists" and "File readable"